How can I set up a non-Spring multi-tenant database using hibernates @TenantId annotation
I have an application that I am trying to switch from a single tenant to a multi-tenant database. I am using hibernate-core 6.5.2 dependency in my pom file. This backend was not set up using spring and has been updated to use Java 21, Tomcat 10, a newer hibernate, etc. FYI I don't have experience with multi-tenancy. I am not wanting to do a different database per tenant or different schemas per tenant. I want to use the @TenantId annotation provided by hibernate and combine that with a tenant_id column on every table of the database to discriminate between clients. For the purpose of this question please assume I have all of the database tables updated with tenant_id, all of the entities updated to include a tenant_id column and the @TenantId annotation, and I am able to get the tenant_id from security context and store it in a static final ThreadLocal string. So far I have been working from examples online and have not done much-
Inside the persistence.xml I added -
<property name="hibernate.current_tenant_identifier_resolver"
                      value="com.security.TenantIdentifierResolver"/>

I also created this class-
public class TenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {
    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        return TenantFilter.getTenantIdFromContext();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }
}

With this alone I am getting the error - org.hibernate.HibernateException: SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified
Any ideas what I am missing?

Okay, after an entire day of trying everything I could, it started working for me. There was one change made inside the persistence xml-
<property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver"
                  value="com.security.TenantIdentifierResolver"/>

This change may have been the answer to my dilemma but I'm 100% positive I had tried this previously with no success. Just throwing this out there but if anyone can point me towards a good multi-tenancy resource to fully understand hibernate I would appreciate it. I feel like their own documentation is severely lacking, not to mention there is also a lack of articles or discussion about it online.
